# man's/woman's bathroom or a bathroom for men/women?

Tags: compound-nouns

If I'm in a place where is only a bathroom for the opposite gender and I want to ask if there is a bathroom for people of my gender should I say:

> Do you know if there is a man's/woman's bathroom around here?

OR

> Do you know if there is a bathroom for men/women around here?

Comment: You can ask "Is there a men's/women's room?"

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=men%27s+bathroom%2Cwomen%27s+bathroom%2Cman%27s+bathroom%2Cwoman%27s+bathroom&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmen%20%27s%20bathroom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwomen%20%27s%20bathroom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cman%20%27s%20bathroom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoman%20%27s%20bathroom%3B%2Cc0) showing that we nearly always pluralise the "adjectival possessive" nouns in ***men's bathroom, women's bathroom***, even when the relevant bathroom itself is singular (and obviously OP only needs to find ***one**!* :)